# Counting Correct Configurations of a 5*n board (Dynamic Programming, C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, dynamic-programming

The problem is as follows: 
Write a program that determines the number (modulo `m`) of white/black patterns on a `5*n` square grid, which do not contain any of `p` forbidden patterns.

The input data has the following format: the first row contains 3 comma separated integers: 
`n` - number of columns, `p` - number of forbidden patterns , `m` - the modulus. The following `3*p` lines contain 3 character long strings consisting of either `.` or `x`, with `.` representing a white field and `x` representing a black field. These are the forbidden patterns, for example:

```
x..
..x
.xx
```

This is my dynamic algorithm for solving this problem:

Let a 3 column "block" be represented by a 15 bit long bitset, with the bits mapping to the columns as follows (1 == black, 0 == white):

```
0 5 10
1 6 11
2 7 12
3 8 13
4 9 14
```

Read the input data and construct all the bitsets representing the forbidden patterns (unused fields are set to 0). Create a vector of bools and under each each index with a binary representation equal to a forbidden pattern set the value to `true`. Do the same for indices which represent forbidden patterns bit-shifted to the left by 1 and 2 (because a forbidden pattern might start in the first, second or third row of a column).

Now, create 2 vectors of integers, `left` and `right`, each with a size of 1024 (2^10). The indices in these vectors represent configurations of 2 column "blocks". In the i-th iteration, the values in the `left` vector represent how many different correct configurations of the board end with a 2 column pattern represented by the index of this vector in the (i-1)-th column. Now iterate through all 32 possibilities for the 3rd column and add that column to the 2 column pattern, each time checking if such 3 column pattern doesn't contain a forbidden pattern. If it does, skip to the next possibility for the 3rd column, if it doesn't than take the value from the `left` vector representing the first 2 columns of the 3 column pattern and add it to the field of the `right` vector representing the 2 column pattern made up of the 2nd and 3rd columns. After all possible 2 columns were considered, swap the vectors, initialise the `right` vector with 0s and repeat the process until we reach the `n-th` column.

The answer is the sum of all the fields from the left vector (since the last operation swaps the vectors).

I hope that is clear, if anything needs a clarification, please leave a comment.

My implementation returns correct results only when the forbidden patterns have at least 1 x in both the top and bottom row, i.e:

```
x..
...
..x
```

I just can't figure out what the problem is. If anything in the code is unclear, please let me know and I will edit this post to clarify that.

Here is my implementation:
http://pastebin.com/2ZPjiyuj

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

ostream& operator<< ( ostream& os, const vector<uint32_t>& v )
{
  for( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++ )
  {
    os << *it << "\n";
  }
  return os;
}

inline bitset<15> make_pattern()
{
  char field;
  bitset<15> pattern;

  for( uint32_t offset = 0; offset < 3; offset++ )
  {
    cin >> field;
    if( field == 'x' ) pattern.set(offset);

    cin >> field;
    if( field == 'x' ) pattern.set(offset + 5);

    cin >> field;
    if( field == 'x' ) pattern.set(offset + 10);
  }
  return pattern;
}

int main()
{
  uint32_t n, m, p;
  cin >> n;
  cin >> p;
  cin >> m;

  vector<bool> forbidden_patterns( 33000 );

  for( uint32_t i = 0; i < p; i++ )
  {
    auto pattern = make_pattern();
    forbidden_patterns[pattern.to_ulong()] = true;  // true := forbidden; false := allowed.
    forbidden_patterns[(pattern << 1).to_ulong()] = true;
    forbidden_patterns[(pattern << 2).to_ulong()] = true;
    //cout << forbidden_patterns[(pattern<<3).to_ulong()];
    //cout << pattern.to_ulong();
  }

  for( uint32_t i = 0; i< 33000; i++ ) //checking the contents of the forbidden_patterns vector
  {
    bitset<15> bs = i;
    if(forbidden_patterns[i] == true)
      cout << bs << "\n";
  }
  cout << "\n\n";

  //bitmasks for setting 2 rows of a 3 column pattern to 0;
  bitset<15> bottom_rows_reset_mask;
  bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(3); bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(8); bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(13);
  bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(4); bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(9); bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(14);
  bottom_rows_reset_mask = ~bottom_rows_reset_mask;

  bitset<15> top_rows_reset_mask;
  top_rows_reset_mask.set(0); top_rows_reset_mask.set(5); top_rows_reset_mask.set(10);
  top_rows_reset_mask.set(1); top_rows_reset_mask.set(6); top_rows_reset_mask.set(11);
  top_rows_reset_mask = ~top_rows_reset_mask;

  bitset<15> top_and_bottom_reset_mask;
  top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(0); top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(5); top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(10);
  top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(4); top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(9); top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(14);
  top_and_bottom_reset_mask = ~top_and_bottom_reset_mask;

  vector<uint32_t> left( 1024, 1 );
  vector<uint32_t> right( 1024, 0 );

  for( uint32_t column = 3; column <= n; column++ )
  {
    for( uint32_t first_2_columns = 0; first_2_columns < 1024; first_2_columns++ )
    {
      if( left[first_2_columns] == 0 ) continue;
      for( uint32_t third_column = 0; third_column < 32; third_column++ )
      {
        bitset<15> t_patt = (first_2_columns | third_column << 10) & top_and_bottom_reset_mask.to_ulong();
        //cout << t_patt << "\n"; //getchar();
        if( forbidden_patterns[t_patt.to_ulong()] == true )
        {
          //cout << t_patt << "\n"; getchar();
          continue;
        }

        t_patt = (first_2_columns | third_column << 10) & bottom_rows_reset_mask.to_ulong();
        //cout << t_patt << "\n"; //getchar();
        if( forbidden_patterns[t_patt.to_ulong()] == true )
        {
          //cout << t_patt << "\n"; getchar();
          continue;
        }

        t_patt = (first_2_columns | third_column << 10) & top_rows_reset_mask.to_ulong();
        //cout << t_patt << "\n"; //getchar();
        if( forbidden_patterns[t_patt.to_ulong()] == true )
        {
          //cout << t_patt << "\n"; getchar();
          continue;
        }

        t_patt = first_2_columns | third_column << 10;
        //cout << t_patt << "\n";
        auto next_2_column_pattern = (t_patt >> 5).to_ulong();
        //t_patt = next_2_column_pattern; cout << t_patt << "\n"; getchar();
        right[next_2_column_pattern] = (right[next_2_column_pattern] + left[first_2_columns]) % m;
      }
    }
    left.swap(right);
    right.assign(1024, 0u);
  }
  uint32_t sum = 0;
  for( int i = 0; i < 1024; i++ )
    sum = (sum + left[i]) % m;

  cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: For reference, this is my friends program solving this problem. It returns correct results for all input data: http://pastebin.com/eUjVUr8B

Comment: `I just can't figure out what the problem is.`  Did you use your debugger to see where your program goes awry?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't crash or leak memory - it simply returns wrong answers for certain types of input data, so there must be some subtle logical error in there that corrupts the calculations.

Comment: The debugger is there to see where your logic doesn't fit with what is actually occurring.  It isn't there just to solve crashes and leaks.  Please single step through your program and see which variable, function, loop, etc. goes against your design.

Comment: First, the debugger is the tool you must learn to use.  That is exactly what one of us has to do to solve your problem -- use the debugger (no programmer actually runs the program "in their head" and remember all of the different variables, states, etc.).   I suggest you start with a simple "Hello World" program and use the debugger to single step through that program.  Also, what compiler are you using?  If it's Visual Studio, then the debugger is right there in the IDE menu ("Debug").

Comment: Also, reduce your sample size down to something you can manage.  33,000 loops is way too much.  If there is a problem, it would / could happen with a much smaller sample.

Comment: I've managed to hone in on the issue a bit - if a pattern without an x in the bottom or top row is given, then my program "finds" more forbidden configurations than it should, i.e it enters one of the "ifs" in the inner loop too many times (though the patterns it enters those ifs with are actually forbidden). Example: input data: 3 1 1000000 ...xxx... , my program enters the ifs in the innermost loop for a total of 415 times, when it should do so only 191 times.

Comment: I knew it was a subtle error :D....

Comment: ok, so did you use the debugger to figure out that the number of times that were being looped were too many?  If so, then that's good.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't quite know how to check the sum total of entries into those 3 innermost ifs using the debugger (though I certainly will learn that in the very near future) - after noticing that my program under-counts correct configurations I've placed a counter variable inside those ifs to track how many times my program enters them and compared that number to the correct number I got from doing the same in my friend's code.

Comment: This program has to be sent to an automated program checker by midnight tonight, so I was under too much deadline pressure to learn how to debug the right way (using the debugger), although the experience definitely motivated me to learn how to use a debugger very soon ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem myself (though PaulMcKenzie deserves a big thank you for sending me in the right direction).

The problem was that my algorithm did not distinguish between forbidden patterns that were shifted by 0, 1 or 2 bits to left. When input data only had patterns containing at least 1 x in the bottom and top rows then all was fine, but once a pattern with only .'s in the top or bottom row was given, then the program began to misbehave.

Consider a forbidden pattern without any x's in the top row - after shifting it 1 bit to the left, the top two rows of this pattern become zeroed. One of the innermost loop's ifs in my program sets the top 2 rows of a pattern being tested to zeroes and compares what's left against the forbidden_patterns vector, where it can possibly be matched to one of those patterns without any x's in the top row shifted by 1 bit to the left! This is logically faulty because a forbidden pattern that has been shifted 1 bit to the left starts in the 2nd row, whereas a pattern with the top two rows zeroed can only contain a forbidden pattern starting in the 3rd row. This caused my program to enter the innermost loop's ifs more often than it should, thus "under-counting" correct configurations.

The solution to this was very simple - split the forbidden_patterns vector into 3 vectors - 1 containing patterns without any shift, 1 containing patterns shifted by 1 to the left and the 3rd containing patterns shifted by 2 to the left. Appropriate vector would then be used in the innermost loop's ifs.

Fixed code:
http://pastebin.com/WCb8eB9F

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bitset>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

inline bitset<15> make_pattern()
{
  char field;
  bitset<15> pattern;

  for( uint32_t offset = 0; offset < 3; offset++ )
  {
    cin >> field;
    if( field == 'x' ) pattern.set(offset);

    cin >> field;
    if( field == 'x' ) pattern.set(offset + 5);

    cin >> field;
    if( field == 'x' ) pattern.set(offset + 10);
  }
  return pattern;
}

int main()
{
  uint32_t n, m, p;
  cin >> n;
  cin >> p;
  cin >> m;

  vector<bool> top_forbidden_patterns( 32768 ); // top_forbidden patterns can only be compared to 3 column patterns that have the top 2 rows zeroed.
  vector<bool> mid_forbidden_patterns( 32768 ); // mid_forbidden patterns can only be compared to 3 column patterns that have the top and bottom row zeroed.
  vector<bool> bottom_forbidden_patterns( 32768 ); // bottom_forbidden patterns can only be compared to 3 column patterns that have the bottom 2 rows zeroed.

  for( uint32_t i = 0; i < p; i++ )
  {
    auto pattern = make_pattern();
    bottom_forbidden_patterns[pattern.to_ulong()] = true;  // true := forbidden; false := allowed.
    mid_forbidden_patterns[(pattern << 1).to_ulong()] = true;
    top_forbidden_patterns[(pattern << 2).to_ulong()] = true;
  }

  //bitmasks for setting 2 rows of a 3 column pattern to 0;
  bitset<15> bottom_rows_reset_mask;
  bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(3); bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(8); bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(13);
  bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(4); bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(9); bottom_rows_reset_mask.set(14);
  bottom_rows_reset_mask = ~bottom_rows_reset_mask;

  bitset<15> top_rows_reset_mask;
  top_rows_reset_mask.set(0); top_rows_reset_mask.set(5); top_rows_reset_mask.set(10);
  top_rows_reset_mask.set(1); top_rows_reset_mask.set(6); top_rows_reset_mask.set(11);
  top_rows_reset_mask = ~top_rows_reset_mask;

  bitset<15> top_and_bottom_reset_mask;
  top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(0); top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(5); top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(10);
  top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(4); top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(9); top_and_bottom_reset_mask.set(14);
  top_and_bottom_reset_mask = ~top_and_bottom_reset_mask;

  vector<uint32_t> left( 1024, 1 );
  vector<uint32_t> right( 1024, 0 );

  for( uint32_t column = 3; column <= n; column++ )
  {
    for( uint32_t first_2_columns = 0; first_2_columns < 1024; first_2_columns++ )
    {
      if( left[first_2_columns] == 0 ) continue;
      for( uint32_t third_column = 0; third_column < 32; third_column++ )
      {
        bitset<15> t_patt = (first_2_columns | third_column << 10) & top_and_bottom_reset_mask.to_ulong();
        if( mid_forbidden_patterns[t_patt.to_ulong()] == true )
          continue;

        t_patt = (first_2_columns | third_column << 10) & bottom_rows_reset_mask.to_ulong();
        if( bottom_forbidden_patterns[t_patt.to_ulong()] == true )
          continue;

        t_patt = (first_2_columns | third_column << 10) & top_rows_reset_mask.to_ulong();
        if( top_forbidden_patterns[t_patt.to_ulong()] == true )
          continue;

        t_patt = first_2_columns | third_column << 10;
        auto next_2_column_pattern = (t_patt >> 5).to_ulong();
        right[next_2_column_pattern] = (right[next_2_column_pattern] + left[first_2_columns]) % m;
      }
    }
    left.swap(right);
    right.assign(1024, 0u);
  }
  uint32_t sum = 0;
  for( auto el : left )
    sum = (sum + el) % m;

  cout << sum;
  return 0;
}
```